# result of ajax call goes to error function

Tags: php, ajax

hey iam trying to build a android pack, backend on php with phonegap. All are perfectly working on localhost. While in server i can't login. Login is checked using ajax, but it doesn't give success. But i can work on localhost. whats the problm? can you help me?

```
function handleLogin() { 
    var fnUrl = base_url+"auth/mob_log";   
    var form = $("#loginForm");  
    var u = $("#username", form).val();
    var p = $("#password", form).val(); 
    if(u != '' && p!= '') { 
        $.ajax({
            url: fnUrl,
            data: {"u": u,"p":p}, //returns all cells' data
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (res) {
                if (res.log == '1') {
                    window.localStorage["username"] = u;
                    window.localStorage["password"] = p;              
                    checkLoginAuth();           

                } else{ 
                    alert(res.msg)  
                    $("#edLogin").removeAttr("disabled");                
                }
            },
      //this errormsg is showing while login

            error: function () {
                alert('Something went wrong.Contact Support')
            }
        });
    } 
    else {
        alert("Enter Username and Password") 
        $("#edLogin").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    return false;
}
```

**php**

```
function mob_log() {     

    $username = $this->input->post('u');      
    $password = $this->input->post('p');      
    $login_result = $this->ion_auth->login_mob($username,$password);   
    if($login_result == 1)
    {
        $this->load->model('login_model');                       
        $p_details=$this->login_model->get_p_details($this->input->post('u'));  
        $p_id = $p_details->id;
        $out = array(
        'log' => '1',
        'p_id' => $p_id,
        'msg'=>'Logged in'
        );   
        echo json_encode($out); 
    }
    else
    {    
        $out = array(
        'log' => '0',
        'msg'=>'Unable to login'
        );   
        echo json_encode($out);             
    }

}
```

Comment: alert(res);  and check what is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = "u": u,"p":p};
$.post(fnUrl, data)
                .done(function (res) {
                    alert(res);
                    res = $.parseJSON(res);
                    if (res.log == '1') {
                         window.localStorage["username"] = u;
                         window.localStorage["password"] = p;              
                         checkLoginAuth();           

                    } else{ 
                         alert(res.msg)  
                          $("#edLogin").removeAttr("disabled");                
                    }
                });
```

Furthermore use console.log and alert function to track the contents of the values.

Comment: $.post is a shorthand function, and it makes the code clearer. I added an alert so you can directly see the output

Comment: still i couldn't make it

Comment: all functions are working on the php side, so i think , it couldn't access the controller through url

Comment: What does alert(res) pop up say to you?

Comment: Then the link in your ajax call is not going the right place. Have you double checked it? Below  var fnUrl = base_url+"auth/mob_log";  please add alert(fnUrl);. And show check its outcome.